# type-graphql Cannot find module 'class-validator' exception

Tags: express, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I am trying to create a GQL mutation by TypeORM and using SQL Server as database. If I am trying to run the mutation it is throwing exception. Sharing the code below;

**index.ts**

```
(async () => {
    const app = express();
    
        await createConnection();
    
        const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
            schema: await buildSchema({
                resolvers: [UserRegistrationResolver, HealthResolver],
            }),
            tracing: true,
            context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res })
        });
    
        apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false });
    
        app.listen(4000, () => {
            console.log("App is started");
        })
     })();
```

**GQL Types:**

```
@InputType()
export class UserRegistrationType {

      /*......*/
      @Field()
      Reg_Security_Qus_Ans: string;
     /*......*/

}
```

**Entity:**

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class User_Registration extends BaseEntity {

          /*......*/

    @Field(() => Int)
    @OneToOne(()=> Security_Questions)
    @JoinColumn()
    Reg_Security_Qus_ID: Security_Questions;

         /*......*/
}
```

**Mutation:**

```
@Resolver()
export class UserRegistrationResolver {
@Mutation(() => User_Registration)
     async createRegistrations(
                @Arg("RegistrationMutation") registrationMutation: UserRegistrationType
          ) {
                console.log("Boom1");
                let oneUser = await User_Registration.insert(registrationMutation);
                return oneUser; 
          }
    
          @Query(() => User_Registration)
          getUsers() {
                console.log("Boom");
                return User_Registration.find();
          } 
}
```

When, I am trying to execute the mutation some weird error is appearing like below, asking me for **'class-validator'**, the error looks something like this,

```
"message": "Cannot find module 'class-validator'\nRequire stack:\n-
```

Can anyone help me to solve this. I am stuck with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was stupid, I had to install

```
npm i class-validator
```

this package. thats all

Comment: Same bruh, was about to curse my internet out lol

Comment: Not stupid.  
npm 7+ installs absent peer dependencies automatically.  
npm 6- does not.  
We discovered this when trying to build on the server recently.  But thank you for verifying.  We ran into the same error again because the server's npm version got reverted.

Answer (score 4):

Either install `class-validator` or use `validate: false` option of `buildSchema`.

Comment: I had to install `class-validator`, even though `validate` was set to `false` in my `buildSchema`